# Cannot copy to file share located in D drive

Tags: file, copy, network-shares

I have a weird permissions issue. I have a service running (made in c#) on a machine (Call this Machine A) that generates files and copies those files to a remote share on another machine (Machine B). On Machine B, I had two shares set up, one in the C drive (Share C) and one in the D drive (Share D). Machine A can copy files to Share C without any problems however has issues copying to Share D. I've triple checked to see that Share C and Share D have the same permission settings so I am at a loss of why I can't copy to Share D. I've even given full access to everybody on the D: drive itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was with Windows 7 and it was a folder permissions problem.  From the link below it sounds like your version of Windows has the same problem:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/cbebc83f-7a4e-4cc5-b13c-13cf21c6ad25/

I think the folder problem is similar to the problem you have.  You should try to do their recommendations on all the servers to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @jyim89 If you found this acceptable please click on the large downward facing arrow to "Accept" this and then you can click on the upwards facing arrow to indicate that it was useful, if you desire... Thanks!!